# Better folders, which support drag & drop: is that even possible?

Tags: app-widgets, drag-n-drop, home-screen-folders

I've tried three different folder widgets for Android 2.3, but I noticed none of them supports adding applications via drag & drop, like the native folders do.

Is that even possible to do?

*I guess it isn't, or those application would be pretty stupid not to support it, but you never know.*

Comment: I'm guessing you're unhappy with how native folders work.  Is it looks, or something else?

Comment: @Chance: mostly how it looks, also how it doesn't apparently allow me to rearrange the icons inside, and how it doesn't close itself when I launch an item inside it.

Comment: Would you consider a different launcher?  Go launcher, specifically.

Comment: @Chance I might think about that

Comment: For the close-on-launch behaviour, and the ability to sort differently, I would recommend [Folder Organizer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.abcOrganizer). There is also a lite version. I've used this app for a long time and really like it. Tho as people have said, it doesn't support drag-n-drop adding, because the OS doesn't expose that kind of hook to apps.

Comment: For what it's worth, Ice Cream Sandwich (aka Android 4) allows drag-and-drop to and from folders, as well as rearranging icons within folders.

Comment: @offby1: uh? Even Android 2 allows drag&drop to _native_ folders, here we are talking about non-native ones, which are widgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only interactions presently supported by app widgets on the home screen are simple click events.  So the answer to your question is no, drag & drop isn't available with widgets.  The reason the native folders can do this is because they are just part of the launcher activity so can be programmed to do more complex things than the widgets can

Answer (score 1):

[Go Launcher](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex&hl=en) will address a couple of the items you mentioned in the comment to your question.  The aesthetics are superior, displaying an "iPhone style" in which it shows a preview of the icons inside of it.  You can also control the behavior of the folder after launching an app, such as whether or not the folder stays open.

I believe you can arrange the icons in any order inside the folder - This screenshot seems to indicate that you can.
[image]